# How to call system function with entity framework core for postgreSQL

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

There is a postgreSQL function "pg_try_advisory_lock(key bigint)" that returns bool result. Is there any solution how can i execute this function and get result via EF Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core doesn't currently support running queries which return primitive (non-entity) types, [#11624](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11624) tracks that.

However, it's very easy to drop down to ADO.NET and execute your function:

```cs
await ctx.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
using var conn = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection();
var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(8)";
var result = (bool)await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
await ctx.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
```

Comment: Yes, I did it the same way.